# CSS only transparent arrow after section

Tags: css

Im trying to find out how I can make an transparent down pointing arrow after a section like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkwk6.png

I have tried numerous things and I can't find any way to do it.

```
.intro:after {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
left: 50%;
bottom: -1px;
height: 31px;
background: #f9f9f9;
content: '';
-moz-transform: skewX(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
-o-transform: skewX(-45deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
transform: skewX(-45deg);
margin: 0 14px;
}

.intro:before {
left: auto;
right: 50%;
-moz-transform: skewX(45deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
-o-transform: skewX(45deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
transform: skewX(45deg);
}
```

Like that, although that makes it wider than the view.

Comment: >i have tried numerous things .... where are they??? show us???

Comment: transparent down pointing arrow....what does it mean????..if the arrow is transparent..how can one display it

Comment: I meant that it should inherit the background from the section, white on the sides and a transparent arrow pointing down in the middle, if you check the image it's a gradient background on the top and a white background at the bottom which is the next section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you looking for. I had done for a project

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/kqZMf/6/

I used the border technic on a pseudo element and draw a colored triangle

```
.nav > li > ul:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
right:15px;
top:0px;
border:15px solid #db7e11;
border-bottom-color:transparent;
border-left-color:transparent;
border-right-color:transparent;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate from here http://cssarrowplease.com/

```
.arrow_box { position: relative; background: #88b7d5; border: 4px solid #c2e1f5; } .arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before { top: 100%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; } .arrow_box:after { border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0); border-top-color: #88b7d5; border-width: 30px; left: 50%; margin-left: -30px; } .arrow_box:before { border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0); border-top-color: #c2e1f5; border-width: 36px; left: 50%; margin-left: -36px; }
```

Comment: This isn't doing it, i need the arrow pointing down to inherit the background from the section (or being transparent like ------\Transparent/-------)